# Azure API Management can't add additional body parameter for the Oauth2 setting

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I have several dataverse APIs that I want to manage in API Management, so I created App Registration and used that Client ID to generate tokens. I tried this in Postman and it works fine, I want to set up my API Management so first I add Oauth2 and then in my API, I use this Oauth2 setting for the API. Then I tried to test it, and the token was generated but I still got the unauthorized response my first guess is that when generating the token I don't add a resource parameter which is my dataverse URL. then I go back to my Oauth2 setting and I just notice there is no parameter to add that. Then I went to search in Google and I found the old API Management has a parameter so we can add the resource there. Did they remove it or is this a bug? Or maybe there is a new way to add the parameter when generating a token?
This is the new API Management
[image]
And this is the old API Management I found on the internet
[image]

Comment: Can you try to pass the resource parameter like `https://login.microsoft.com/tenant_id/oauth2/token?resource={resource}`, I believe it should work.

Comment: Hi @IkhtesamAfrin I'm using the v2 endpoint do you suggest using v1 endpoint?

Comment: If you are using V2 endpoints, then there is no need to pass resource as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-oauth2#configure-an-oauth-20-authorization-server-in-api-management, it says `If you use v2 endpoints:
* Enter the back-end app scope you created in the Default scope field.
* Set the value for the accessTokenAcceptedVersion property to 2 in the application manifest for both the backend-app and the client-app registrations.`

Comment: Hi @IkhtesamAfrin It still doesn't work, the audience of the token is not my dataverse URL. hence I still got the unauthorized response

Comment: What value you are passing for scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have configured OAuth2 in Azure APIM in order to call Dataverse APIs in the following way-

Using v2 endpoints for Oauth2 configuration.

[image]

Enabled OAuth 2.0

[image]

I am adding the Authorization code grant flow Redirect URI in Entra.

[image]

[image]

Made `"accessTokenAcceptedVersion": 2` in Manifest and below changes in API permissions.

[image]

[image]

After making all these changes, I invoked below URL using Developer Portal.

```
GET https://org******.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.2/WhoAmI
```

Once you select authorization_code, you will get prompted to login. Post successful login, bearer token will get amended to the request header.

[image]

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

Try to pass the scope as `https://*********.crm.dynamics.com/.default` and follow my steps, you get the output too.

Comment: Ohh I see, so set the scope as our dataverse URL. Thank you so much it works now.  But I still wonder why we can't add an additional body hahaha.  they don't mention any of this in their documentation.